# Json error when making post request to server

Tags: python, ios, json, flask, swift3

After hours of searching through stack and reviewing similar questions I still cannot get this to work. Please help guide me!

All I am trying to do is submit a username to my server and save it in MySQL - just to get it working...

I can send the username through to the server and even return hardcoded data back to the iOS simulator to set a label's text, **but as soon as I add the function to save the data to MySQL, I get the error: "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}"**

Sorry for weird naming conventions, I am deviating from a tutorial I was following.Thank you!

**SWIFT 3:**

```
func Apitest(name: String) {

    let json = ["user" : name]

    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)

        let url = NSURL(string: "I put the actual path here, don't worry")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = jsonData

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data, response, error in
            if error != nil{
                print("First Error -> \(error)")
                return
            }
            do {
                let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                print("Result -> \(result!)")

                let label = result?["messages"] as! String

                print(label)

                self.setupLabel(text: label)

            } catch {
                print("Second Error -> \(error)")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

**API code (python/flask)**

```
@app.route('/api/get_messages/') methods=['POST'])
def get_messages():
json = request.get_json()

api_test(json['user'])

return jsonify({'messages':json['user']})
```

**MySQL function:**

```
def api_test(user):
c, conn = connection()
c.execute("INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (%s)", (user))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
c.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code I would say your insert command should be:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (%s)", (user))
```

Comment: Sorry, it actually is that. I didn't paste that line in, I typed it.